# Reversing UITableView with custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reverse

I have a reverse UITableView, to reverse it I apply a CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1) on the tableView and on each cell.

[image]

I populate my table view with custom cells (label + 2 buttons).
Each button inserts a new custom cell above the previous cell, and so on.

The custom cell data are set via a local .plist.

[image]

The issue is after a number of cells added, the behavior changes. When the label finished to display fully, the buttons appear, but the button1 is already highlighted and impossible to selected.
I don't understand (and find) why...

A git project reveals more than a thousand words, so my project sample:
https://github.com/cmii/ReverseTableView

In this sample the issue appears when inserting the 5th cell.

Comment: I'm not at my desk so I can't test. I think you are dequeueing a cell and then using it without resetting it. There are only enough cells created by the system to accommodate the visible cells. After that they are re-used. Use either table view prepareCellForReuse or set the properties to nil after dequeueing a cell.

Comment: Is it the fault to the code : self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ParagraphTableViewCellView", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ParagraphTableViewCell") ? I read it's necessary in Swift 3.0

Comment: No.  It's because you already changed the cell the previous time you used it, and didn't undo those changes when you reused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dequeueing a cell and then using it without resetting it. There are only enough cells created by the system to accommodate the visible cells. After that they are re-used.Here's an example using your code. When you create a cell you do this:

```
 //le bouton sélectionné est mis en avant
            if button == sender as! ChoiceButton {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            }
```

What happens when you turn it yellow, it goes off the screen, you dequeue it and then reuse the cell without "cleaning it up"? Even if it is not a ChoiceButton, it will be yellow, because it already was yellow.

The easiest way to fix this in your configureCell method. Do the same check, but if it is not a ChoiceButton, you turn it back to the normal color (I'll use clear in this example):

```
   func configureCell(tableView: UITableView, cell: ParagraphTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
...
     //le bouton sélectionné est mis en avant
                if button == <someBoolean> {
                    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
                } else {
                    button.backgroundColor = .clear
                }
...
}
```

If there are other issues, now you understand where they are coming from, so you should be able to fix them yourself.  Good Luck!